# MySQL INSERT syntax using foreign key

Tags: mysql, insert, foreign-keys

I've got this problem.. it's soon not problem, but i want not to use more than one query if it is possible.

i want to insert data in the table using data from another table. here's example:
i have table1:

```
TABLE1
id  name  value  max_data  diff
```

AND Here's is table2

```
TABLE2
id name max_data
1  nm1  8000
2  nm2  9000
3  nm3  9500
4  nm4  9600
...
```

While inserting i know id from table2 and i want to use name and max_data from it. Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (value, diff, name, max_data) VALUES (5.0, -0.3, table2.name table2.max_data) WHERE table2.id = 3
```

Comment: You cannot use a 'where' clause in an insert statement, unless it's an `insert ... select from` type query.

Comment: This had nothing to do with a foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
insert into table1 (value, diff, name, max_data)
select 5.0, -0.3, name, max_data
from table2
where id = 3
```

You can include whatever literals you want in a SELECT clause. You can also use this technique to insert multiple rows at once.

Comment: multiple rows.. u mean if i will not insert id in where clause, it will insert same value and diff for each row from table2?

Comment: @Ika: If your `select ...` produced three rows then that would insert three rows (probably with different `name` and `max_data` values). If `table2.id` is the primary key then you'll only get one row inserted.

Comment: okey. it will help me in a lot details in my code.
And code above works fine. Thank you @mu